# Trying to redirect a certain directory to a filename

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to intercept HTTP requests for two specific directories:

```
/mydir/
/thisdir/
```

Whenever someone requests one of those two, they should be served `/mydir.html` and `/thisdir.html`, respectively. All other directories should behave as normal.

I can get it to work for *all* directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/ $1.html [QSA]
```

But my attempts to get it to work just for the two particular directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/(mydir|thisdir)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/ $1.html [QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(mydir|thisdir)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/ $1.html [QSA]
```

result in the directory index being displayed.

Comment: Have you tried putting a trailing slash at the end of your RewriteCond condition?

Comment: Yes, both like this `^/(mydir|thisdir)/$` and like this `^/(mydir/|thisdir/)$`.

Comment: Try deactivating MultiViews (`Options -MultiViews`) – it often interferes when handling situation like this.

Comment: Are you going to `/mydir/` or `/mydir`?

Comment: @JonLin I've tried both, it works for neither.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(mydir|thisdir) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(mydir|thisdir)/?$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Tried it as you've written it--same result: the directory index shows up.

Comment: It worked on my Apache. Are you just entering `http://domain.con/mydir/`? Does `/mydir/` also have htaccess? Are there more rules?

Comment: `/mydir/` and the other don't have `.htaccess`, and there are no other `.htaccess` rules anywhere on the site but what I'm testing now.

I'm actually working from a subdirectory dev environment, so it's actually `http://domain.com/dev/mydir/`. The root of `domain.com` does not have `.htaccess` rules.

Comment: Yes! that's it. Thanks. so `\s/+(mydir|thisdir)` was grabbing it from the root, but `/(mydir|thisdir)` just grabs it from the end of the URI?

Comment: Right this one just matches it in the middle of the URL however `RewriteRule ^(mydir|thisdir)(/.*)?$` matches it from start of **current directory**.

Comment: One more thing--this doesn't allow files inside the directory to work. I'd still like to be able to access `/mydir/file.html` normally. I thought putting `/(mydir|thisdir)$ [NC]` would do that, but now it breaks everything again.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(mydir|thisdir)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1.html [R=301]
```

Comment: Same result--directory index is displayed.